# Difference between %()s and {} in Python 3.6 with Postgres

Tags: python, string, postgresql, formatting

I was wondering if someone can explain to me why...

this doesn't work where I use this %()s style of python formatting for both variables:

```
some_column = column
some_id = id

db.execute(
    f"""
    SELECT %(some_column)s
    FROM schema.table_name
    WHERE id = %(some_id)s
    """,
    {
        "some_column": some_column,
        "some_id": some_id,
    }
)
```

but this works where I use {} formatting for the column and %()s formatting for the where clause:

```
some_column = column
some_id = id

db.execute(
    f"""
    SELECT {some_column}
    FROM schema.table_name
    WHERE id = %(some_id)s
    """,
    {
        "some_column": some_column,
        "some_id": some_id,
    }
)
```

Comment: can you add snippet where you are replacing values? or you have to check this https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Comment: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters

Comment: The question is incomplete for us to advice. Could you reference a link to the library you're using? Also, what are the values of some_column/some_id that gives you the error?

Comment: I guess the syntax for %s is wrong. If you look closely, while passing the parameters to string, you need to pass % also, which is missing. Correct if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The new python3.6 f strings uses the `{}` inside the string to be replaced at **runtime**
so if you want to use the f strings your code should be

```
some_column = column
some_id = id

db.execute(
    f"""
    SELECT {some_column}
    FROM schema.table_name
    WHERE id = {some_id}
    """)
```

that is it, the string will evaluate the **code** inside the `{}` and replace it with the variables values.